# PHP exception is caught, but error message still appears

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I use some code from the PHP manual to make an exception test, but I get some weird message.

Here it is the code:

```
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    else return 1 / $x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo 'Hello World';
```

And here it is the output:

```
0.2
( ! ) Exception: Division by zero. in /var/www/OOPlearing/slash.php on line 10Call Stack#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation10.0002330188{main}(  )../slash.php:020.0002330232inverse( $x = 0 )../slash.php:17Dump $_SERVER$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] =string 'localhost' (length=9)$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] =string 'localhost' (length=9)Dump $_GETVariables in local scope (#2)$x =int 0
Caught exception: Division by zero.Hello World
```

It's strange that although the exception has been caught, the exception message is still on...

Some of my local settings in php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors =On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = Off
......
html_errors = On
```

My notebook:

```
ubuntu11.04
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.54
PHP 5.3.5-1
```

**Update(2012.1.16)** It's the xdebug extension that resulted in such error outputs. The xdebug default shows stack traces on error conditions. For those who want to disable it can do below instruction:

```
xdebug_disable();//put it on the header of your code,like cofig file.
```

[more details](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_disable)

Comment: did you try setting `display_errors` to off?

Comment: Turning of error reporting is not a solution of problem ;)

Comment: I copy-paste you code and it show just 
0.2
Caught exception: Division by zero.
Hello World.
So no problem

Comment: @rkosegi this is due to the extra verbosity of error reporting in php's config... so it's not actually a problem, it's the way it's meant to work... what is your error reporting config in php.ini?

Comment: @jere: You're right, my mistake, error_reporting = E_ALL, but display_error = Off

Comment: @jere,i have pasted some ini settings which i think would affect the error repoting...Is there something i miss to paste?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you try/catch() a block of code then you wont get a fatal error of "Uncaught exception". A fatal error will cause the script to stop executing at the point of the error. Since you caught the exception, it did what you told it to: Echo the string + error message, then it continued execution to "Hello World!". If anything your error reporting is more verbose due to your INI settings, like the stack trace printout.

Comment: ,so i want to know which ini setting will result in the extra error reporting...should i paste a complete list of my ini settings here?

Comment: the same result...maybe the xdeug affected the error output.i will try to disable it later...anyway,thanks...

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to disable xdebug and you do not want the trace message to appear, you can turn off the display of the exception trace with

```
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
```

in your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want errors to be displayed, then turn off error_reporting and display_error. It would then show you only the message that the exception is printing out

Answer (score 1):

Setting `display_errors = off` will give you the behaviour you want, but be aware you won't get **ANY** error messages or warnings, so unless you are in a production environment it's highly recommended you leave this on.

If you don't want to turn off error reporting for all php, you could do one of these:

- set `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 0); ?>` at the top of your script.
- create a virtualhost for your site (if you don't already have one) and create an .htaccess and include the line `php_flag display_errors "1"`

hope this helps